# HTML/CSS workaround menu-toggle only works on first elemet

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a page that once a div is clicked, all of the pertinent information is displayed. So once a league is clicked upon, the games for that league are displayed. I am using the following workaround to avoid javascript:

CSS:

```
  #game-info-toggle:checked + #game-menu {
    display:block;
  }
```

HTML

```
<% @leagues.each do |league| %>
  <label for="game-info-toggle" class="cursor-pointer">
    <div class="w-1/4">
      <%= league.title %>
    </div>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="game-info-toggle" />
    <div class="hidden" id="game-menu">
      <% league.games.each do |game| %>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <h1><%= game.teams %></h1>
          <h1><%= game.assignment.center_referee&.name %></h1>
          <h1><%= game.assignment.assistant_referee_1&.name %></h1>
          <h1><%= game.assignment.assistant_referee_2&.name %></h1>
          <h1><%= game.assignment.fourth_official&.name %></h1>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The problem I've run into is that this works great for the first instance of leagues but does not work for the following.

Initial State:

[image]

When I click on any League, only League 1 games appear as so:

[image]

Desired outcome if I was to click on each League individually (League 1 & 2 here):

[image]

Comment: ids should be unique, you have multiple identical ids. Suggest you change game-info-toggle and game-menu to class attributes.

Comment: Would having those as class attributes still work or am what I am trying to implement only work with id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

1. The labels need to have unique associations with the inputs, but you have many labels and inputs with the same id.
2. Having fixed the unique associations of label and input in 1, you have lost the id fields to control the css to show the games. So add classes for css show/hide control.

```html
<% @leagues.each do |league| %>
  <label for="game-info-toggle<%= league.id %>" class="cursor-pointer">
    <div class="w-1/4">
      <%= league.title %>
    </div>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="hidden game-info-toggle" id="game-info-toggle<%= league.id %>" />
  <div class="hidden game-menu" id="game-menu">
    <% league.games.each do |game| %>
      <div class="mb-4">
        <h1><%= game.teams %></h1>
        <h1><%= game.assignment.center_referee&.name %></h1>
        <h1><%= game.assignment.assistant_referee_1&.name %></h1>
        <h1><%= game.assignment.assistant_referee_2&.name %></h1>
        <h1><%= game.assignment.fourth_official&.name %></h1>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```css
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .game-info-toggle:checked+.game-menu{
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: I think there is a typo? Should league.id be league_id? And it also did not work. It just gave the same result as I initially had. If you know of a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: @wayoh22 it's definitely league.id, assuming that the League model has an id field. I tried it and had it working... let me see if I made a typo. Obv I don't have a League or Game model so I had to translate what I had available.

Comment: @wayoh22 oh yes I made an error translating from haml (which I used to test it) to html... I've fixed that and it works here... give it a try